# Search and Replace with RegEx components in Atom editor

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I want to search and replace this

```
`https://example.com/`{.uri}
```

to

```
[https://example.com/](https://example.com/)
```

With `vim` I would do a `s/`(http.*)`{.uri}/[\1](\1)/g` but that doesn't work with `atom.io`. How can I solve this?

Comment: I could also use `vim`. I'd like to know how to solve the given problem with `atom`.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

If you Cmd-F and open the search pane, there is a ".*" button at the right side. Click it and now it's regex mode.

I find

```
(http.*)\{\.uri\}
```

and replace to

```
[$1]($1)
```

Comment: `s/(http.*){.uri}/[\1](\1)/g` doesn't work in `atom` with RegEx activated. Maybe it is a bug or a different RegEx syntax. That was the reason of my question.

Comment: I find "(http.*)\{\.uri\}" and replace to "[$1]($1)". It works. This is the perl-style regex, which I believe is the standard.

Comment: @speedogoo You should submit this as the correct answer.

Comment: Any idea how do I eval the captured group to do some stuff on it before replacing? For example, if `$1` captures a number group - 123, replace it by adding 1 to it, something like `eval($1+1)`..?

Comment: Using dollar for back referencing doesn't work for me. Is it still accurate ? I'm using atom v0.205.0 and find-and-replace package in version 0.170.0.

Comment: Ok I just forgot to use parentheses in the regex. Just ignore what I said.

Comment: To reproduce a find functionality similar to Sublime Text: Type `command` + `F`, type in your search, and then hit (on a Mac) `option` + `return`. If the Find All option is selected, this will create multiple cursors you that allow you to edit the search matches directly.

Answer (score 20):

Juste to update [*@speedogoo's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22367119/4927984) for future readers, if you do not find the regex mode in the search view, it looks like this:

[image]

You can also open it with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> *(default)*.

---

*Note that even `^` and `$` [are already supported](https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/497) by Atom's find-and-replace.*

Comment: Are you saying that Group Replace doesn't work with Atom, thereby making the accepted answer wrong (and ruining my day with Atom)?

Comment: I believe he meant that start of line `^` and end of line `$` anchors are not supported. Group replace is supported.

Comment: It works in recent versions, the linked github issue has been closed.