# How can I "Find and Replace" specific characters inside TAGS using ATOM?

Tags: regex, replace, find, atom-editor

I need help replace the **-** inside my **alt** tags only (not the rest of the code/html).

> bad: alt="Tumble-drying-allowed"
>
> good: alt="Tumble drying allowed"

I'm using ATOM and the REGEXP tutorials are foreign to me. (so weird to look at)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<td data-colname="File"><strong><img title="Tumble-drying-allowed"
src="wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Tumble-drying-allowed.svg"
alt="Tumble-drying-allowed" width="31.18" height="31.48" />Tumble-drying-allowed</strong>
File name:Tumble-drying-allowed.svg</td>
```

Eventually I'll target the **title** tag too, but I need a head start

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex string which will find alt= + a string joined by hyphens

```regex
alt=['"]{1}([A-Za-z]*[\-]{1})*[A-Za-z]*["']{1}
```

and here is one the find alt= + a string joined by spaces

```regex
alt=['"]{1}([A-Za-z]*[ ]{1})*[A-Za-z]*["']{1}
```

Over to you to see how you use them in atom-editor.
NB I've made it so that it will find '' or "" as string delimiter. Your might have a problem with these characters if you use it in a script.

Comment: WOW, the first part is amazing! Thanks for this.
How do I replace my findings?

bad: alt="Tumble-drying-allowed"

good: alt="Tumble drying allowed"

Comment: Are you on Windows? Linux? Are you ok with a script to search and replace in a text file?

Comment: Nice Kendle! :)
I'm using "ATOM" the editor on Windows. It has a search replace like sublime or word.

Comment: Does it have regex capacity?

Comment: See this post on regex find and replace in atom https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220444/search-and-replace-with-regex-components-in-atom-editor

Comment: LOL this is WAY over my head, I'll change them manually. I really do appreciate your efforts. ! :-D xo